# Can I use a Navigo Semaine to go for Chantilly Castle?

Tags: public-transport, paris

I've a Navigo for zones, but I'm not sure if it's valid to go for Chantilly Castle.

My credits are valid from Gare de Lyon to Chantilly Chateau?

Comment: Yes @pnuts but I still don't know if all areas also means Castle of Chantilly. Do you know?

Comment: Great destination.  If you cannot get there on your Navigo, hopefully you'll find another way.

Comment: @Dorothy why don't you make that an answer?! While your last link does not work for me, [this map](https://www.transilien.com/sites/default/files/atoms/files/plan_idf_sncf_v2016-01_1.pdf) clearly states "tarification hors Ile de France".

Comment: @mts ouch :-( instead of [SNCF](http://en.voyages-sncf.com/en/) I copied my search; will answer, correct, and delete my comments. thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Navigo Semaine package is valid throughout the Île-de-France zones 1-5, it could not be used for a direct trip to Château de Chantilly, which is located outside Zone 5.

[**SNCF**](http://en.voyages-sncf.com/en/) shows it as a 50-minute journey from Paris Nord to Chantilly-Gouvieux for 8,70 €; the castle is about a 15-minute walk from the station.

**[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris/Ch%C3%A2teau-de-Chantilly)** is also a useful tool to explore options and alternatives, and a [map of your route](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris/60500-Chantilly-France). And @pnuts has thoughtfully provided this map of all your [transport options within all of the Île-de-France zones](https://www.transilien.com/sites/default/files/atoms/files/plan_idf_sncf_v2016-01_2.pdf).

Comment: @pnuts good reference